# How to bind the published port to specific eth[x] in docker swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I'm trying to deploy my container to docker swarm cluster(docker engine 1.12.1).

The features of **docker swarm mode** really are exciting, such as clustering docker, multi-host networking.

However I find something can't be archived in swarm mode so far(**docker 1.12.x**), which works well when using `docker run` to start container.

My host has **eth0** for Intranet network, **eth1** for Internet network. I would like to only publish the service deployed by `docker service create` on Intranet network. But the service would listen both **eth0** and **eth1** interfaces after creating the service via `docker service create --name my_web --publish 8000:80 my_web_image`.

Any solution/workaround to archive the **my_web** service only listening on **eth0** interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like this is currently [not supported](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26696).